# image not in 100% full height when browser in full screen mode

Tags: html, css, image

I have created a simple website which changes images every few seconds. All images are in landscape.
When my browser is in normal view mode, the images cover the entire height of the browser, however when i change my browser to full screen mode, the image did not cover the entire height of the browser, in fact there's a gap at the bottom of the page. below is screen shot of my website and css code. can any tell me what's wrong and how to fix it?

**Below image shows the white empty space at the bottom of the image (highlighted in red)**
[image]

**CSS Code**

```
          style type="text/css">
                        * {box-sizing: border-box;}
                        body {
                            font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
                            height: 100%;
                            }
                        .mySlides {display: none;}
                        img {vertical-align: middle;}

                        /********************************** Slideshow container **********************************/
                        .slideshow-container {
                              position: fixed;
                              top:0;
                              left:0;
                              width:80vw;
                              height:100%;
                              z-index: 1;
                        }

                        .slideshow-container img{
                           max-width:100%;
                           height:auto;
                           max-height:100%;
                        }
/********************************** Fading animation **********************************/
            .fade {
              -webkit-animation-name: fade;
              -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
              animation-name: fade;
              animation-duration: 2s;
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes fade {
              from {opacity: .4} 
              to {opacity: 1}
            }

            @keyframes fade {
              from {opacity: .4} 
              to {opacity: 1}
            }

            /* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
            @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
              .text {font-size: 11px}
            }

    </style>

<body>
        <div class="slideshow-container">

                <div class="mySlides fade">
                  <img src="image/1.jpg">
                </div>

                <div class="mySlides fade">
                  <img src="image/2.jpg">
                </div>

                <div class="mySlides fade">
                  <img src="image/3.jpg">
                </div>
     </div>
</body>
```

Comment: the css property `object-fit` might help

Comment: @jcal tried your method but there is problem, some part of the images got cut off.

Comment: @Honestman if you want an image to fill an arbitrary rectangle (like a screen) you have to pick one of the following: (1) some space won't be covered, (2) some of the image will be cut off, (3) the image will be stretched/distorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution might be to modify your image wrapper and image style

```
.mySlides{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.slideshow-container img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

By the way, your code should have worked at first. Maybe the image is not filling the container.

Answer (score 0):

For full screen of image width:100% has to use.